# Updates in Redux state set the entire state of the React component to its initial state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have been asking question about the same bug I have been stuck with in the past days, details can be found here: [Problems in displaying redux state changes in react components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62012881/problems-in-displaying-redux-state-changes-in-react-components/62017160#62017160). Now I got some clues: The reason why the modal (approach 1) or the MatchingBox component (approach 2) did not show up was that the updates in the Redux state (props to the WaitingRoom component) somehow set the entire state of the component to its initial state. Thus, "showmatchingwindow" was set to false as well. Initially, after MATCHING_REQUEST was dispatched and "loading" was set to true, the state of WaitingRoom component still remained unchanged. However, after MATCHING_SUCCESS was dispatched and "loading" turned false and buddy" and "chatid" in the Redux state got updated, all the fields in the state of WaitingRoom were somehow reset to their initial values. This is weird and did not happen with my other Redux actions. I am wondering whether anyone can help me explain what caused this. Really appreciate your patience and any help you can offer!

Comment: Please update [your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62012881/1218980), do not post update questions. Don't forget to try to keep the content to the minimal required to demonstrate the problem. That's what's explained in the [mcve] help page.

Comment: Got it, have updated my original post!